# How to import the google map timeline Json data into a DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas

I got my commuting report from google map timeline and it is in json format. I use these codes:

```
with open('Location History.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
  data = json.loads(data_file.read())
  pd.DataFrame(data)
```

the dataframe has only one 'location' column.

```
{"locations" : [ {
"timestampMs" : "1501812184856",
"latitudeE7" : 390632197,
"longitudeE7" : -771227158,
"accuracy" : 10,
"velocity" : 1,
"heading" : 226,
"altitude" : 146,
"verticalAccuracy" : 12
 }, {
"timestampMs" : "1501813902831",
"latitudeE7" : 390624516,
"longitudeE7" : -771212199,
"accuracy" : 10,
"velocity" : 5,
"heading" : 316,
"altitude" : 126,
"verticalAccuracy" : 16
 },
```

any advice how I can read the file into multiple columns and one row for each member of dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extract 'location' from initial json, and then convert to DataFrame

```
with open('Location History.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())

pd.DataFrame(data['locations'])
```

Comment: But I need the lication, date, hours in each location ( commuting time) and so on. So i need all fields not just location. Any thought?